# 403 Forbidden error when registering custom domain for my django website

Tags: django, linux

I am new to Django,I was following a tutorial on how to deploy a site using ngnix ubuntu and gunicorn,I bought a domain at namecheap and the site is hosted by LinodeBut whenever.Every step was succesful,no errors when I checked for gunicorn status,he server also restarts succesfully ,but I when I visit the domain I get a 403forbiden error.
I have checked out for similar problems but none of them are of help

settings.py

```html
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.devbrian.com',]
```

sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/blog

```html
server {
       listen 80;
       server_name  wwww.devbrian.com;
       location = /favicon.ico {access_log off;log_not_found off;}
       client_max_body_size 100M;
       location  /static/ {
         root /home/brian/blog;
       }
       location  /media/ {
         root /home/brian/blog;
       }

       location  / {
         include proxy_params;
         proxy_pass http://unix:/home/brian/blog.sock;
       }
     }
```

sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```html
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
}
```

Comment: thats permission error give file permission to your django project folder

Comment: I am still new to django and site deployment ,can you kindly show me or provide a link how to set the permissions

Comment: First point : in your nginx conf you have "wwww.devbrian.com" (4 "w") - you may want to double check this. If this is not the issue, you first have to check your nginx and gunicorn / django logs to find out if the problem is with nginx conf (requests don't even make it to your Django project) or with django itself (requests reaches the gunicorn/django processes, but something in your project / settings / install prevents them from being served).

Comment: Also you want to make sure your site's conf (nginx conf) is linked in the sites-enabled directory.

Comment: @PavanKumarTS while it _might_ come from a file permission issue, the 403 response doesn't _necessarily_ mean it's a file permission issue.

Comment: Thanks you so much @brunodesthuilliers for helping me identify the silly mistake I made, It turns out the error was caused by the extra 'wwww'.It works fine now

Comment: I once wasted a lot of time trying to understand why one of my SQL queries raised a syntax error. I finally asked a co-worker for help, and It turned out I had misspelled "UDPATE" for "UPDATE". I swear I _did_ check the whole query's spelling a hundred times or more, and still never spotted this :facepalm:

Comment: True,these tiny typo's cab be  really frustrating